# require_once not needed in PhpStorm Docker dev container

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm developing a small app in PHP using the [PhpStorm, Xdebug & Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/phpstorm/php-71-apache-xdebug) container. When I do a new of a class existent in the project in another folder I don't need to use `require_once` before the new sentence.

But if I deploy the code in an Ubuntu + Apache with dev mode disabled, it fails because he can't find the class.

Once I add the require_once before the new It works as expected. I have been looking through the Xdebug docs and I haven't found a reason for this behaviour. What is the docker container doing to autoload the class without the `require_once`?

Edit: I'm not using composer, It's only plain PHP. I have an autoloader.php for loading the libs but It's my code an is the same in both environments. It also loads my controllers.

Edit 2: The [image](https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-docker-images/blob/master/php-71-apache-xdebug-25/Dockerfile) I use includes the composer command installed fom the [composer](https://github.com/composer/docker/blob/main/2.2/Dockerfile) image. Could it be something related to this? I don't see anything suspicious but I'm no expert.

Comment: Most likely you do not import (composer?) autoloader. From issue description I would check if there is any PHP autoloaders implemented and check if they are working )or even exists in container)